# Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0, wampserver

When I run my baked table (WampServer MySQL database), I get this error:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Users.user_id' in 'on clause'
>
> If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT `Bookmarks`.`id` AS `Bookmarks__id`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`user_id` AS `Bookmarks__user_id`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`title` AS `Bookmarks__title`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`description` AS `Bookmarks__description`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`url` AS `Bookmarks__url`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`created` AS `Bookmarks__created`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`modified` AS `Bookmarks__modified`,
       `Users`.`id` AS `Users__id`, 
       `Users`.`email` AS `Users__email`, 
       `Users`.`password` AS `Users__password`, 
       `Users`.`created` AS `Users__created`, 
       `Users`.`modified` AS `Users__modified` 
FROM `bookmarks` `Bookmarks` 
    INNER JOIN `users` `Users` ON 
            `Users`.`user_id` = (`Bookmarks`.`user_id`) 
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

If you want to customize this error message, create `src\Template\Error\pdo_error.ctp`.

Comment: Change it to `Users.id` thats what the column is called

Comment: And why do you add round brackets for `(`Bookmarks`.`user_id`)` they serve no purpose

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is a CakePHP related question. CakePHP uses a query builder that will generate that specific SQL, so the OP doesn't have too much influence on it with regards to stuff like parenthese placement. Sometimes there are some unneccessary extra parentheses because the compiler doesn't go the extra mile of checking whether they are technically required.

Comment: Most likely your association and/or table primary key config is wrong, please update your question with the corresponding `initialize()` method code of both the `BookmarksTable` and the `UsersTable` class.

Answer (score 1):

In your user table, primary id is `id` not `user_id`; that is why you're getting an error. Try this query instead:

```
SELECT `Bookmarks`.`id` AS `Bookmarks__id`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`user_id` AS `Bookmarks__user_id`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`title` AS `Bookmarks__title`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`description` AS `Bookmarks__description`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`url` AS `Bookmarks__url`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`created` AS `Bookmarks__created`, 
       `Bookmarks`.`modified` AS `Bookmarks__modified`,
       `Users`.`id` AS `Users__id`, 
       `Users`.`email` AS `Users__email`, 
       `Users`.`password` AS `Users__password`, 
       `Users`.`created` AS `Users__created`, 
       `Users`.`modified` AS `Users__modified` 
FROM `bookmarks` `Bookmarks` 
    INNER JOIN `users` `Users` ON 
            `Users`.`id` = `Bookmarks`.`user_id`
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: I think that is what I said 10 minutes earlier in a simple comment

Comment: I see you also picked up my comment about the brackets.

Comment: I suppose I could also give you an upvote as you were so thorough at converting them both into an answer, and the questioner probably will not bother as they are long gone.

Comment: Someone else that does not understand sarcasm!